# I can't find the surface dropdown in the material tab

Tags: displacement

[image]

It looks like this, and I want to change the Displacement value from Bump only to Both so that the mesh has a real bump not just a fake one. Did blender have done an update?

Comment: This only works in the Cycles Engine. Make sure you have it set to Cycles in the render properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to illustrate Gorgious's comment.

*Material options* depend on the selected Render engine.
To get *Displacement settings*, you need to switch to *Cycles.*

[image]